# Android Textview with clickable email and link

Tags: android

I have textview with clickable email and link. My text has link and email

my xml is:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimeTopBar"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sms_deposit_information"
        android:textColor="@color/sms_deposit_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:autoLink="email"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/smsNumberField"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dividerBottom" />
```

But I have a problem. When I put android:autoLink="email" it shows email and makes it clickable and not link. If I remove it shows link clickable and not email.
What should I do?

Comment: `android:linksClickable="true"` add this attribute

Comment: it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the `android:linksClickable="true"` attribute.

> If set to false, keeps the movement method from being set to the link movement method even if autoLink causes links to be found.

Set the `sms_deposit_information` in strings.xml in the form of

```
<string name="sms_deposit_information"><![CDATA[<p>abc@xyz.com</p>]]></string>
```

Then do the below programmatically

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.description);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.sms_deposit_information)));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: what is the text here. I want when user clicks on word "HERE" open link. what is the word and what is the url in your example?

Comment: can you write one short example in this html way with address and link in string?

Comment: Also this way my whole text lininig and spacing (because I need to make it as design says) is lost since HTML makes it his way

Answer (score 4):

Can you try adding attributes as:

```
android:autoLink="email|web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Comment: No, still not working. only email is shown the right way

Answer (score 0):

put a String in xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="test">Support: <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">click here</a></string>
</resources>
```

TextView

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/test" />
```

**EDIT**
add this code too:

```
TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: try removing `android:gravity="center"  ,  android:linksClickable="true"` this two line and  keeping this `TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`